# react - router withRouter does not inject router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I want to use withRouter on my top-level React component called 'App'.

Documentation is here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.4.0/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md#withrouter-hoc-higher-order-component

I use it like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {Router, Link, hashHistory, Route, IndexRoute, withRouter} from "react-router";
import VoteView from "./voteview/Voteview.jsx";
import OverView from "./overview/Overview.jsx";
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

//Needed for onTouchTap
//Can go away when react 1.0 release
//Check this repo:
//https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin
injectTapEventPlugin();

const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <AppBar
                title="Democratizer"
                onTitleTouchTap={()=>this.props.router.push('/')}
              >
              </AppBar>
              <br/>

            {this.props.children}
          </div>
      );
  }
});

render((
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="voteview/:baselineId" component={VoteView}/>
          <IndexRoute component={OverView}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  ), document.getElementById('app'));

module.exports = withRouter(App);
```

I want to use withRouter(App) in order to make Appbar Title clickable. If the user clicks it, the default "/" path should be opened. That is what I try to achieve with `onTitleTouchTap={()=>this.props.router.push('/')}`.

My problem is that the router is not there. When the user clicks on the title in the Appbar, it triggers an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

withRouter(SomeComponent) works fine for me for components further down the component tree. But I cannot get it to run in this case.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is happening because you are injecting the router after you render the react app.

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <AppBar
                title="Democratizer"
                onTitleTouchTap={()=>this.props.router.push('/')}
              >
              </AppBar>
              <br/>

            {this.props.children}
          </div>
      );
  }
});

App = withRouter(App);


render((
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="voteview/:baselineId" component={VoteView}/>
          <IndexRoute component={OverView}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  ), document.getElementById('app'));
```

A better solution would be creating a file for App like you have done with the other components.

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <AppBar
                title="Democratizer"
                onTitleTouchTap={()=>this.props.router.push('/')}
              >
              </AppBar>
              <br/>

            {this.props.children}
          </div>
      );
  }
});

module.exports = withRouter(App);
```

and import it in your index.js.

Comment: works: you can see it in action here: https://github.com/nemoo/democratizer/tree/master/app/assets/js