# React-router New page renders and previous component stays on page after doing browserhistory.push('/path')

Tags: react-router, reactjs

I have a routing setup like this in my app:

```
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <Route path="/books" component={Main} url='/polls/getbooks/'/>
     <Route path="/books/bookdetail" component={BookDetail} />
   </Route>
 </Router>
```

My App component looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    pageContent() {
      let content = <Spinner/>;

      if (!this.props.dataLoading) {
         content = (
           <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
             component="div"
             transitionName="bobon-transition"
             transitionEnterTimeout={500}
             transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
             transitionAppear={true}
           >
           { React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
             key: this.props.location.pathname
           }) }
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
     );
   }
   return content;
 }

    render() {

      let content = null;

      if (!this.state.authed) {

        content = (
            <div className="pf-authed">
              <AppHeader/>
              <div className="bobon-page-content page-content">
                { this.pageContent() }
              </div>
              <AppFooter/>
            </div>
       );} else {

        content = (
            <div className="pf-authed">
              <AppHeaderAuthed/>
              <div className="bobon-page-content page-content">
                 { this.pageContent() }
              </div>
              <AppFooter/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is my Main component:

```
class Main extends React.component {

  render() {

   if(!this.state.loaded) {
      return <Spinner/>
   }

   if(this.state.authed) {
      content = (
                <div >
                    <BookList apiData = {this.state.childData}/>
                </div>
                );
   } else {
      content = (
                <div>
                    <LoginForm/>
                </div>
                );
    }
    return content;
  }

}
```

When the user is logged in the page renders correctly and he sees the 'BookList' component. However in Booklist I navigate to a 'BookDetailView' using browserHistory.push('/books/bookdetail') when the user selects a book. The issue is that on the book detail view the 'BookList' component stays on page and the page looks like this:

```
<BookDetail>
<BookList>
```

If I was to type into my browser /books/bookdetail then the view would render correctly as

```
<BookDetail>
```

Why is the 'BookList' rendering on the bookdetail when I use browserHistory.push() page?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In previous versions of React Router (version 2.0.0) we used to:

```
import { browserHistory } from './react-router'

// then in your component
browserHistory.push('/books/bookdetail')
```

In newer versions of React Router (version 2.4.0) we can use `this.props.router.push('/books/bookdetail')`. In order to do so you need to use the **`withRouter` wrapper**. This can be done, for example, when exporting your `BookList` component.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class BookList extends React.Component {
  clickHandler() {
    this.props.router.push('/books/bookdetail');
  }
  render() {
  // if used in the render method you can use:
  // <h1 onClick={()=>this.props.router.push('/books/bookdetail')}>Book title</h1>
  }
}

export default withRouter(BookList);
```

More info:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options 
[react - router withRouter does not inject router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225592/react-router-withrouter-does-not-inject-router)

Comment: Hi Piotr, lifesaver!

Comment: Hi Piotr, the problem has cropped back in. I edited my question and added the render method that I use in App.jsx with my header bars. The head components (AppHeaderAuthed) are the ones that do the browserHistory.push('/books/bookdetail") and I think they are responsible for the issue.

Comment: @freeBeerTomorrow it's hard to debug without reviewing the source code for all modules. What happens with the URL when you use  'BookDetailView'? Does it update to '/books/bookdetail'?

Comment: I've also updated my answer with further information on how to use `push()`.