# withRouter Does Not passes Route props to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

Here is my navigation component:

```
import React from 'react'

class Navigation extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      type: 'signUp', // or login
      showModal: false,
      isLoggedIn: false,
    }
  }

  ...some code

  render() {

    const { showModal, type, isLoggedIn } = this.state

    console.log(this.props.location); // all problem is this, I'm not getting it in console

    return(
      ...some more code
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Navigation)
```

And here is where it it been used in app.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return(
      <Router>
          <Fragment>

            <Navigation /> // <= right there

            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
              <Route exact path='/search' component={HomePage}/>
              <Route component={Lost} />
            </Switch>
          </Fragment>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to get updated route props like `match` and `location` and `history` in my `<Navigation />` component *but* I get it only when the first time that component mounts on the DOM, in my other components I update the route using `window.history.pushState` but I am not able to get route props from withRouter after link in the browser is been updated.

I update route with `window.history.pushState` because:

1. I could not find any way to update just link in the address bar without showing user or redirecting user to new component with React router DOM (am I doing it in right way or not?)
2. based on that I then use `window.location.pathname` to add some specific stylings to some components)

Also, I read the entirety of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225592/react-router-withrouter-does-not-inject-router) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174814/using-react-router-withrouter) but I could not solve this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) gives you the closest `<Route>`'s route props, and since the `Navigation` component is not inside a `Route` you will not get the [`route props`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props).

You could e.g. put the `Navigation` component on a `Route` outside of the `Switch` that will always be visible.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Route path="/" component={Navigation} />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route exact path="/search" component={HomePage} />
            <Route component={Lost} />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What an interesting and great usage. I've never seen this before. Thank you @Tholle, noted.

Comment: i applied your method but i realized that since by adding new path to link by `window.history.pushState` , react will checks the changes on navigation component , but wait there is nothing changes in navigation component , so it will not rerenders the navigation component to apply route props on that , and again by that though , i'm still unable to get route props in my navigation component....

Comment: @a_m_dev I'm not quite sure I understand. Why are you using `window.history.pushState` instead of `this.props.history.push`? Don't you want to use the functionality of React Router?

Comment: yes , b/c i noted my reason , i could not find any proper way to ONLY update link instead of updating link and showing new component with react router...

Comment: @a_m_dev Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. I don't get why you would want to change the URL but not change what `Route` is active.